# Deserialize an Array section from within a JSON file into a List

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core

I have the following valid json that contain a list/Array of databases,

```
{
        "Logging": {
            "IncludeScopes": false,
            "LogLevel": {
                "Default": "Debug"
            }
        },
        "settings": {
            "name": "",
            "path": ""

        },
        "Databases": [{
                "key1": "",
                "key2": "",
                "key3": ""
            },
            {
                "key1": "",
                "key2": "",
                "key3": ""
            }
        ]
    }
```

I am using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject in C#

If also have a method and classes for getting the json into a RootObject List and it works great.

```
public static List<RootObject> GetConfig() {
                System.IO.StreamReader s = new StreamReader(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\appsettings.json");
                List<RootObject> cfg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(s.ReadToEnd());
                return cfg;
            }
```

What I want to do now is to have a new method that return a list that only contain the Databases, (not the logging, settings sections in the json)

something like this

```
public static Databas GetDatabaseSetting(string key) {
            System.IO.StreamReader s = new StreamReader(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\appsettings.json");
            List<Databas> dbs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Databas>>(s.ReadToEnd());
            foreach(var c in dbs) {
                if(c.key== key) {
                    return c;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

but I could not get that to work.

How can I create a list of databases from only the database settings section from the json file

Comment: It's not typical to parse `appsettings.json` manually. This is all handled out-of-the box when using `IConfiguration` and the default setup. Do you have different requirements that force you to parse `appsettings.json` manually?

Comment: You can't just say "I want that part" without deserializing the entire thing. Also, what stops you from returning `RootObject.Databases.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Key == key)`? This apart from what @Kirk says, of course.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
IConfigurationSection dbArraySection = _config.GetSection("Databases");

var dbArray = dbArraySection.AsEnumerable();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using this in ASP.NET Core you can register your class

```
public class DatabaseCatalog
{
     List<Database> Databases { get; set; }
}

public class Database
{
    public string Key1 { get; set; }
    public string Key2 { get; set; }
    public string Key1 { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your Startup.cs you add

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    IConfigurationSection dbsSection = Configuration.GetSection("Databases");
    services.Configure<DatabaseCatalog>(dbSection);
}
```

And you can inject that into your class like

```
public class Something
{
     private readonly DatabaseCatalog _dbsc;
     public Something(IOptions<DatabaseCatalog> dbsc)
     {
           _dbsc = dbsc.Value;
     }
}
```

From there you can assign

```
List<Database> dbs = _dbsc.Databases;
```

Comment: Why it has +3? `keyX` was obviously just an example ... what if there will be `key4` ... first part of this answer looks like  **json to C# class  generator output**

Comment: Keys are just property names that he should put that match the names of the json properties

Comment: from the question is obvious that they are dynamic ... so using  json2poco (or what ever) output as answer is not a way

Comment: It wasnt obvious to me to be honest but if it is something like that then he must use reflection to see if property names match in the json so that he can deserialize them

Comment: @Selvin I agree with @Mycenaean. It looks strange to have dynamic attributes in `appsettings.json`. I would like to suggest to use json2poco approach and to add an array instead of variable list of keys to the `Database` class, like `"Databases": [{"Keys":["value1", "value2", ... ]}]` and poco object like `class Database { public string[] Keys {get; set; } }`

Comment: It's nothing strange with dictionary and `Databases` looks like list of dictionaries not list of POCOs

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-strings#aspnet-core hehe ... they are using "strange dynamic attributes" as names for connection strings - we are doomed - it's in official docs

Comment: Yea but he is still searching by a string key, so he can technically do something like this JObject propObject = JObject.Parse(json); and search like this  JProperty jProperty = propObject.Property(key, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase); right? he can return that JProperty as an object.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it post deserialisation with Linq

```
public static Database GetDatabaseSetting(string key, IEnumerable<RootObject> objects) 
{
    return objects.SelectMany(o => o.Databases).SingleOrDefault(d => d.Key == key);
}
```

But as Kirk has asked re: processing appsettings.json, normally you would use the out of the box connection strings available to you:

```
{
    "Logging": {...}
    "ConnectionStrings": { "BloggingDatabase": "connection string here" }
}
```

And in Startup use:

```
Configuration.GetConnectionString("BloggingDatabase");
```

If you want to use it in other services, you can pass an IConfiguration dependency.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-strings

Answer (score -1):

```
public class DBObj
{
    public List<Item> Databases { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public string Key1 { get; set; }
    public string Key2 { get; set; }
    public string Key3 { get; set; }
}
```

And then

```
var db = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DBObj>(json);
```